# Is there any simple analytic method for solving $\sqrt{x}+y=7$ and $x+\sqrt{y}=11$ simultaneously.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

I am thinking of a nice and simple analytic method to solve the following equations simultaneously:

$$\sqrt x+y=7;\\x+\sqrt y=11.$$

To my suprise I can't. But, I solve the system numerically using Newton's method and the solution is $4$ and $9$.

Is there any simple way of solving the above system analytically?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531345/system-of-equations-sqrtxy-11-and-x-sqrty-7

Comment: Have you tried substitution $x = u^2$,$y=v^2$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Raise to power of two both equation and eliminate the squares.